# jqwidgets grid Entity Framework LINQ paging

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Referring to the example on:
http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/asp.net-integration/asp.net-grid-server-side-paging-sorting-filtering-mvc3.htm

I was wondering if there is a different, more generic way, of pulling out the data from Entity Framework for Sorting, Paging, Filtering insted of instantiating a specific model class. Not having this:

```
 var query = Request.QueryString;
 var dbResult = db.Database.SqlQuery<Order>(this.BuildQuery(query));
 var orders = from order in dbResult
              select new Order
              {
                  ShippedDate = order.ShippedDate,
                  ShipName = order.ShipName,
                  ShipAddress = order.ShipAddress,
                  ShipCity = order.ShipCity,
                  ShipCountry = order.ShipCountry
              };
```

But something that would be the same no matter what the model is.

I have tried with:

```
  var orders = db.Orders.AsEnumerable();
```

but then EF complains about the entity already being loaded. 
I need something that would be the same for all models with changing just SqlQuery, I want to build a T4 scaffolding for Index view.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

i don't know much about jqwidgets but it needs some data to configure paging and sorting from server side. that means you need to send some class in serialize which represents paging sorting data.

most simply it may look like

```
public class Pager<T>
{
    public int TotalRows { get; set; }
    public List<T> Rows { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
}
```

for the case of generic solution to queries you can create data layer something like 
as mentioned in this post

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application